# Use DNS TXT records for wallet address resolution?

Tags: wallets, addresses, user-experience, dns

Are there any Ethereum wallet projects using DNS TXT records to resolve wallet addresses?

Setting a TXT record would allow users to have a human readable wallet "address", eg

```
$ dig example.com TXT
example.com.    3600    IN    TXT   "eth:0xde0b295669a9fd93d5f28d9ec85e40f4cb697bae"
```

Some proposals for formatting have been made by [OpenAlias](https://openalias.org/) and [ma.ttias.be](https://ma.ttias.be/proposal-cryptocurrency-addresses-dns/)

Comment: That's the obvious solution, though it looks like they want to sell their non domain mappings instead.

Answer (score 1):

This does exist and is called Ethereum Name Service. Check it out: https://ens.domains

Comment: Yes, I've seen that project. Using TXT records doesn't require purchasing a new domain, which is nice

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in testing this out, I created a small `npm` package to query a domain for OpenAlias TXT records: https://www.npmjs.com/package/openalias